# Executing VBScript file remotely - file not found

Tags: psexec

I tried using

```
psexec \\emeagdmv28apx50 -s -i Test1.vbs

psexec \\emeagdmv28apx50 @file "C:\Start.ps1"
```

But the script is not able to find the file on remote machine. I have this particular file present at the localhost as well as the remote machine on the same path.

**Error I get**

```
PsExec could not start Test1.vbs on emeagdmv28apx50:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

#### But the script is not able to find the file on remote machine

Execute the `.vbs` file on the remote machine using `cscript`:

```
psexec.exe \\computer -u user -p pass c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe script.vbs
```

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [Running vbscript with psexec?](https://serverfault.com/questions/202271/running-vbscript-with-psexec)
- [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) - Execute a command-line process on a remote machine. Execute a command-line process on a remote machine.